# How to align selected tab to center of tablayout?

Tags: android, android-tablayout

I am developing an android application. I need to use a tablayout on a section of the application. But I'm unable to align the selected tab to the center of the tablayout.
Can anyone help me please ?

Comment: Can you provide with images on what you need, and what you have achieved till now.

Answer (score 0):

Gravity used to lay out the tabs in the center of the TabLayout.

`TabLayout_tabGravity = "GRAVITY_CENTER"`

Or

```
  tabLayout.setTabGravity(TabLayout.GRAVITY_CENTER);
```